# XSLT transformation to move an element into another or set it as attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

What is a XSLT template that will get the `<title></title>` that contains the name of a blog and put it in every `<entry></entry>` or as an attribute in every `<entry>` ?

from

```
<feed>
<title>title of feed</title>
<entry>...</entry>
<entry>...</entry>
</feed>
```

to

```
<feed>
<entry><blog>title of feed</blog>...</entry>
<entry><blog>title of feed</blog>...</entry>
</feed>
```

or

```
<feed>
<entry blog="title of blog">...</entry>
<entry blog="title of blog">...</entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You often get better and more answers if you could show a little effort trying to answer the question yourself.

Comment: Agreed. Many of us don't like answering questions unless we feel you are going to learn something as a result (and therefore ask fewer questions in future). If we don't know why you're having problems, then we don't know what you need to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the attribute solution, something like this should work :

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
    <entry blog="{/feed/title}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </entry>
</xsl:template>
```